# SSL_pending functionality with memory BIOs?

Tags: openssl

I'm using 2 memory BIOs (BIO_s_mem) to implement async functionality with winsock.

```c
ssl = SSL_new(this->ctx);

ssl_input = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
ssl_output = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

SSL_set_bio(ssl, ssl_input, ssl_output);
```

Writing socket-received data to the input BIO (`BIO_write(ssl_input, ...`) does not get OpenSSL to update it's internal state. Therefore calling a function like SSL_pending after wrting to the BIO has the same outcome as if I hadn't written to the BIO at all.
The internal state is only updated when calling SSL_read, but I may simply not want to read yet.

One possible solution I thought of is using SSL_peek with a very small buffer size (to avoid wastefully coppying a lot of data I won't use), but I haven't found reason to believe it will consume all the data in the BIO. Even if it worked, sounds like the wrong way to do it.

I do realize calling SSL_read when I *do* need it will ultimately be transparent. It will read from the BIO, do any processing required, and return the data - I know. I would however still prefer to have the functionality of SSL_pending in my wrapper class. Not every write to the BIO results in buffered data (i.e. handshakes, renegotiation, heartbeat) and it's useful to know whether there's any data, without implicitly pulling it out if there is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems SSL_pending works differently from what I initially thought. Even with blocking sockets, the return value represents only the data that is *left* in the SSL buffer. For data to enter the ssl buffer in the first place, an `SSL_read` needs to happen - regardless of whether you have a memory bio or something different.

The SSL object is a state machine, one whose gears only turn when you call either `SSL_read` or `SSL_write`. A memory BIO has no mechanism to make the SSL state machine process it's contents - BIOs are not aware of the SSL state machine, they're only used by it.

<sup>(with the exception of `BIO_f_ssl`, but that behaves differently as it implements it's own ssl object)</sup>

---

> One possible solution I thought of is using SSL_peek with a very small buffer size

The better solution is to follow the `BIO_write(ssl_input)` with `SSL_read(ssl, 0, 0)`.
It updates the SSL state with the contents from the buffer, doesn't copy any data, and since no more than one record can ever be read at any one time (and no data can be read until the record is fully received) we needn't worry about leaving unprocessed data.